# java. Использование приватных статических переменных нарушает ООП?

Tags: java

Если в одном классе я использую приватную статическую переменную, нарушает ли это правила ООП? Получаю я её через геттер в другом классе.
Код , где объявлена статическая переменная:

```
package MainP;

public class Formula{

private Planir plframe;
private static float FreeArea;
private static float AllArea;

(Всякий код...)

    public float Get_FreeArea() {
    return FreeArea;
}
```

Comment: [Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7026563/2881286)

Comment: Почему метод Get_FreeArea не статический? Вот **это** реально бардак (обычно). Во-вторых, не Get_FreeArea, а getFreeArea.

Comment: Спасибо, что сказал ошибки.Я их у себя исправил. В этом коде ещё ошибки есть(согласно правилам ООП)?
Не кидайтесь тапками, я учусь только. :)

Comment: @InSpaceGame, а ты где-то видел список правил ООП?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Приватная статическая переменная ничего не нарушает, но получение ее через get-ер - дурнопахнущий код. Определите для себя почему Вам необходимо ее получать из другого класса, возможно эта переменная находится не там, где Вам нужно.
2. Если Ваш класс Formula является базовым и вы используете его как хранилище констант, то наиболее распространенная практика делать константы как

   ```
   public static final float FREE_AREA;
   ```

   тогда из другого класса можно будет получать ее так:

   ```
   float f = Formula.FREE_AREA;
   ```
3. Если Вы хотите писать на Java, чтоб другие Вас понимали, изучите [соглашения](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)